# Prove property of function using induction.

Tags: functions, induction

Show by using induction that if the function $f(x)$ is a solution to the equation $f(2t)+f(\frac{t}{2})=t$, then $f(x)$ has the following property: $f(mx)=m\cdot f(x)$ for any real number $m$.

So I tried to consider the function $f(kt)+f(\frac{t}{k})=t$.
If we assume that the function $f$ has the property $f(mx)=m\cdot f(x)$, it means that.

$$kf(t)+\frac{1}{k}f(t)=t$$
Any tips for what should I do next?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the reputation to comment yet, so I'll post this as an answer.

You actually only need to prove the case of $m=2$ and $\frac12$: using $f(2t)+f(\frac t2)=t$, it is easy to see $f$ is proportional to $t$, and the claim follows then. But this this shows your claim that $f(kt)+f(\frac kt)=t$ is not true, so you probably want to think otherwise.

Another thing is that I don't see a reason for induction: it is used to prove claims about integers, but (I assume) the domain of $f$ is $\mathbb R$. Maybe some sort of continuity will come into play.